# Is there any way to launch an app (and keep the screen on) when a Galaxy Nexus is docked?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, docking-station

Using the official desktop docking station, my Motorola Xoom (running official Honeycomb 3.2) by default launches the Clock app when the tablet is docked, and keeps the screen on whilst it's docked.

The Settings app on the Honeycomb Xoom has a Dock category with two options "Dock Application" and "Dock Insertion Sound", I can't find any similar options on the Galaxy Nexus.

Is there any (preferably built-in) way to get similar functionality with an (unrooted) Galaxy Nexus using the official Samsung dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spotted that when I put my phone into its dock for the last few days, it now displays a clock (digital style, with the date below, in ICS blue) on the screen while it's charging.

This has happened since the recent Android v4.0.4 update for the Galaxy Nexus. This has also added a "Dock" category under the "System" section in Settings. This has options to enable a "Dock Insertion Sound" and change Audio settings for the dock.

Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could use [DockAwake! Dock Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rmays.DockAwake) for this. To just keep the screen on you can set `Settings -> Developer options -> Stay awake`.

Comment: Thanks, but DockAwake seems to be Motorola Droid only from the Market comments, and [the website](http://www.dockawake.com/), no free version, so haven't tried it. And the Stay Awake while useful, is less useful without an app displaying at the same time.